# Linq Count Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Suppose the following Employee class (yes I know I shouldn't publicly expose Lists but this is just an example):

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<string> Skills {get; set;}
}
```

Skills is just a list of skills the employee has, for example "programming", "customer service", etc.

Now suppose I have a `List<Employee> CurrentEmployees`, and I also have another employee, `Employee NewHire` that is not in the `CurrentEmployees` list.

My goal is to use a lambda expression to count how many employees in `CurrentEmployees` have at least one skill that `NewHire` also has.  So for example, if `CurrentEmployees` contains one employee with `Skills{'Programming', 'Troubleshooting'}`, and another employee with `Skills{'Accounting','Finance'}`, and NewHire has `Skills{'Programming','Networking'}`, I would want an expression that returns 1, because the first employee in the list also has 'Programming' as a skill... is this possible?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 currentEmployees.Count(ce =>
               ce.Skills.Intersect(newHire.Skills).Any())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var currentEmployees = new List<Employee>
{
    new Employee { Skills = new List<string> { "Programming", "Troubleshooting" } },
    new Employee { Skills = new List<string> { "Accounting", "Finance" } },
};

var newHire = new Employee { Skills = new List<string> { "Programming", "Networking" } };

var count = currentEmployees.Count(e => e.Skills.Any(newHire.Skills.Contains));
// count == 1
```

Comment: Thanks.  Could you give me a brief explanation of this?  I'm particularly interested in the newHire.Skills.Contains part.

Comment: @Andrew: that is a method group and get's translated implictely into `x => newHire.Skills.Contains(x)`

Comment: @sehe, that's not exactly correct. For example, you can't convert a method group to `Expression`, but you can do that with the lambda. Method group gets implicitly converted to delegate and the lambda can be implicitly converted to delegate too, but that doesn't mean method group is converted to lambda first.

Comment: @sehe, yeah, but that doesn't mean you should say things that are incorrect.

Comment: (why don't you post a constructive explanation, I'll delete mine)

Answer (score 2):

If performance was important, I would use a `HashSet<string>`:

```
var newHireSkills = new HashSet<string>(newHire.Skills);

var count = currentEmployees.Count(e => e.Skills.Any(s => newHireSkills.Contains(s)));
```

Comment: +1 But, unless people have way too many skills, or the company is China Inc. you should be fine. Meanwhile, add `new HashSet<string>(newHire.Skills, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` to have _efficient, case-insensitive_ skill sets :)